# Radon Nikodym derivative of measures on $\mathcal{B}_{(0,\infty)}$.

Tags: measure-theory

(a) Show that there is at most one measure $\nu$ on $\mathcal{B}_{(0,\infty)}$ which satisfies the following conditions:

1. $\nu((1,e]) = 1$
2. $\nu(cA) = \nu(A)$ for every $c>0$ and $A \in \mathcal{B}_{(0,\infty)}$.

(b) Assuming the measure from part (a) exists and is absolutely continuous with respect to the restriction of the Lebesgue measure to $\mathcal{B}_{(0,\infty)}$, find the Radon-Nikodym derivative.  Was the assumption correct?

I was able to do part (a), but I have no idea how to do part (b).  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $d\nu=fd\lambda$, where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure.

Then for any $A$ and any $c$ you have:
$$
\int_A f(x) d\lambda(x)=\nu(A)=\nu(cA)=\int_{cA} f(x)d\lambda(x)
$$
Now use integration by substitution and see what you can find out about $f$.

Answer (score 3):

The measure $\mu$ is invariant under multiplication, while $m$ is invariant under addition. Define a new measure $\nu(A)=\mu(e^{A})$ for $A \in \mathcal{B}_{(-\infty,\infty)}$. Then 
$$ \nu(t+A)=\mu(e^{t}e^{A})=\mu(e^{A})=\nu(A), $$
and
$$ \nu([0,1))=\mu([1,e))=1. $$
There are not a lot of possibilities.